# Can I place a vessel sink over integral sink without cutting out existing sink. I

Tags: sink

[image][image: ienter image description here]
If I bring counter top to level can I place a vessel sink over existing one?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the sink it might be  possible. If you're talking about one of the larger vessel sinks that lay flat and would completely cover the sink opening then that may work. You'd probably need to cut the sink bowls out of the existing counter top so you can hook up the drain. The one problem you may have is if you will be able to mount the faucet behind the sink.

Comment: I plan on getting a rectangle one and ensuring I don’t cover the faucet holes but I really didn’t want to have to cut out existing sinks.

Comment: I would agree that the drain would need to be opened up to allow the drain connection. I would think if the op just wants the new sink to dump into the old that would be a smelly mess in a short time.+